# Why is Django Class Based view giving error about incorrect number of arguments to __init__()?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a very basic Django class-based view as follows. It doesn't really even do anything:

```
from django.views.generic import View, TemplateView

class index(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'myApp/index.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(index, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

However, when I load this view through the browser, I get the following error:

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
Exception Location: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response, line 112
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.5
Python Path:
```

Why am I getting this error? And how to fix it please?

Below is more context around the location of the error:

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.6.5-py2.7.egg/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response
106.                    response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
107.                    if response:
108.                        break
109.            if response is None:
110.                wrapped_callback = self.make_view_atomic(callback)
111.                try:
112.                    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
113.                except Exception as e:
114.                    # If the view raised an exception, run it through exception
115.                    # middleware, and if the exception middleware returns a
116.                    # response, use that. Otherwise, reraise the exception.
117.                    for middleware_method in self._exception_middleware:
118.                        response = middleware_method(request, e)
```

Comment: Can you show how you are using the view in urls.py?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, thanks! Your question reminded me to check my urls.py and sure enough... I wasn't using the .as_view(). Thanks! When I added that, it fixed it.

Comment: Also, I think you don't need to overwrite the `dispatch` method, in fact, you are just calling the parent. Even, you can avoid the `index` class using `TemplateView` directly in your `urls` `url(...,TemplateView.as_view(template_name = 'myApp/index.html'),name...)` ofc, this is valid only if you don't use `index` class for other purposes as subclass it etc..